# Javadoc - Documenting a POJO

Tags: spring, jpa, javadoc, pojo

I need to document/java-doc the entities in a POJO. For example, if there is a column entity

@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

The column 'id' should be documented such a way that it has basic description of the column and its constraints. Is there any commenting techniques available in java-doc to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Entitys are code but not sourcecode because they are a not a "source", the entitys are a replication (lets say a mirror) of the real source - the database structure.

Please document the source, because the source is the database you should use the comment-functions of the database.

Example in oracle:

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN employees.job_id IS 'abbreviated job title';
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4009.htm#SQLRF01109

Unfortunately this is ASCII but not hot-loved javadoc.

This way:

1. a database-engineer must not know how to code java and
2. you have an interdisciplinary team.